# What is the difference between openmpi compilers?

Tags: c++, openmpi

What is the difference between mpic++, mpicxx and mpiCC? I am not certain when to use which compiler.

More specifically, I am on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS os with a gcc 7.4 compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Open MPI version installed, the manual (`man mpiCC`) says

> Note that mpic++, mpicxx, and mpiCC all invoke the same underlying C++ compiler with the same options.

so at least with this implementation, there is no difference.

Comment: so was there once a difference?

Comment: @BevanJones Complete guesswork: I doubt there was ever a difference, I think different implementations used different names for it originally, there was no convention (just like C++ files often end in .C, .cxx, .cc, etc). Later some provided aliases for the other names.